# I want to give an office 365 user some rights with powershell

Tags: powershell, office365

I want to make an user in office 365, I want to give him some rights.
He has to be able to see all office 365 emails. I don't want him to be a global admin.

Comment: Have you tried the official documentation for this?
https://technet.microsoft.com/library/mt628067.aspx

Comment: Not yet, I will check it out

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt614244.aspx 
I want the user to be able to do this, but the user can't be a global admin.
I have only little knowledge of powershell

Comment: so you told us, what you want... and whats the concrete question ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want grant only Exchange admin rights, go office365 admin portal, choose user > "edit roles" > "Customized administrator" > "Exchange administrator"

But what I tested, Get-MsolUser cmd **doesn't require any admin rights**.
Just install AzureAD powershell module and you are good to go.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt614244.aspx